# Extract all edit data for a Wikipedia page

Tags: wikipedia, wikipedia-api

I'm trying to extract the edit data for a list of cities as found in the [page statistics](https://xtools.wmflabs.org/articleinfo/en.wikipedia.org/Germantown,_Tennessee?editorlimit=200). The previous hyperlink is an example for one city. I'd like to extract the total edits, total number of editors, major/minor edits, IP edits, bot edits, (Semi-)automated edits and reverted edits for a page **using the Wikipedia API**.

I tried using the xtools API [here](https://xtools.wmflabs.org/api/page/articleinfo/en.wikipedia.org/Germantown,_Tennessee) but it only returns the total edits and major/minor edits. Is there a way of obtaining this information using any of the Wikipedia API's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but it will require work on your side to parse the data to give the metrics you are after. e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&titles=Germantown,_Tennessee&rvlimit=500&rvprop=tags|flags|user|comment&format=json contains the information you need, but you will need to process each edit to determine whether it was semi-automated, reverted or edited by an IP.

Comment: I should probably have pointed out that the above query only fetches the 500 most recent edits and so if there are more edits you need to make more calls and add more parameters